# Is there a formula for estimating population size?

Tags: statistics, estimation

If I have a website with a number of registered users, and each user has their geolocation recorded, is there a formula to guestimate the total number of people living in a particular area, e.g. within $1km^2$?

I've just found out about the [German Tank Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) and how remarkably accurate it is with sparse data, but obviously people don't have serial numbers. I'm wondering if there's anything similar, potentially using other commonly collected data such as birthdays, date of account creation, how frequently the site is used, etc.

Comment: If you know the whole population, then you can just use that information (with a little spherical geometry).  Presumably you only know the location of some people (hopefully an unbiased sample) and you want to estimate the population form that.  The natural answer is to scale the proportion in your sample to the population, but it is not the only approach

Comment: If your goal is to estimate the total population within a small region based on participation on the site, I don't see how that is going to work. You would have to know something about the percentage of the population that tends to visit the site--an that may vary by geographical region.